# Resistor surge current rating: Why is the pulse energy withstand capability lower for short duration?

Tags: current, resistors, heat, thermal, inrush-current

As per an online surge capability [calculator](https://www.vishay.com/resistors/SMD-wirewound-pulse-capability-calculator/), the pulse energy withstand capability is low initially and increases with higher pulse width. In short, we are not allowed to pass a narrow high current pulse - hoping the energy content is within limits as short-term overload capability.

[image]

AFAIK this is the sequence of events when current flows through a resistor

1. Heat is generated in resistor (Instantaneous activity)-> Based on i^2 * R *t
2. The heat increases the temperature of resistor gradually -> Based on Qabsorbed = mc∆T and [image]

Where, c is the specific heat capacity, m =mass, Q is the transfer of heat per unit time, K is the thermal conductivity of the body,
A is the area of heat transfer, d is the thickness of the body

[image]

WHAT IS MEANT BY THE STATEMENT  *"This positive sloping section of the curve is when a sufficient amount of time has passed to allow for the heat energy to transfer from the wire into
the surrounding"*

1. Wouldn't heat transfer start to happen the moment there is a temperature difference between 2 surfaces? Higher the body temperature, faster the rate of transfer- I don't understand the mechanism of resistor heating up 'differently' for a large narrow pulse.
2. I am not sure whether thermal time constant comes into picture anywhere.

Comment: Not a detailed answer, but this is generally true for most kinds of parts.  Given some time, heat can spread throughout the part.  So, spreading the application of the energy over longer time results in lower peak temperatures at the hottest points.

Comment: > Wouldn't heat transfer start to happen ... < For the short pulse, it is a thermic "adiabatic" transformation. So "heating" occurs only on the peripheral surface of the "wire" (skin effect). Then heat can spread in and out of this surface ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand the mechanism of resistor heating up 'differently'
> for a large narrow pulse

Let's take this to the extreme.  Imagine I have a 1/4W resistor, and I apply 1/4W to it for 1 year.  In that case I have applied 1/4W * 1 year = 7.88 Megajoules of energy to the part, but because I applied it over the course of one year the heat had time to radiate out of the part.  If I tried to apply that much energy in one second, I would likely vaporize the part and anything near it.

A simple model of heat transfer usually looks like

$$ \frac {dE} {dt} = \frac{T2-T1} R$$

That is to say the rate of energy transfer is equal to the difference in temperature between two points, divided by the "thermal resistance" separating those points.

So, heat does indeed begin to flow immediately, but the energy is not transferred instantly.  Instead, it flows proportional to the temperature difference.

Compared to other things heat moves relatively slowly.  In many cases it might take many hours of operation for the temperature of a circuit card and all its components to stabilize to their final operating temperature.

Another thing to note is that most material have a "heat capacity" measured in Joules per Kelvin, which is the amount of heat (J) required to raise the temperature of the material by 1 K.

In most parts, the heat is not generated uniformly in the whole bulk of the part, but rather in "hot spots".  Those points where the peak temperatures occur are often the failure points.

A thick film SMD chip resistor is typically a non-conductive ceramic substrate with a serpentine resistive pattern printed onto that substrate.

[image]

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/patt-1764178.pdf

Like all materials the substrate has some heat capacity, and therefore it takes a certain amount of energy to raise its temperature.

All of the heat energy is going to originate from that serpentine pattern.  That pattern is the "hot spot".  If the energy is applied fast enough (ms or us) then there will not be much time for the heat to spread into the ceramic substrate (some heat will go into the substrate but very little, like microjoules or millijoules).

But given enough time (a significant fraction of a second) several hundred millijoules or even joules of heat will have moved into the substrate, and in doing so help to lower the temperature of the hot spot.  Ultimately nearly all the heat will move into the PCB or the surrounding air, supporting long term operation of the part while keeping the temperature at reasonable levels.